# Who / whom : The guests whom we were talking about have come are my brothers-in-law

Tags: exam-questions

> The guests whom we were talking about have come are my brothers-in-law.

Which is correct here who or whom ? This [forum](https://www.englishforums.com/English/ProblemInUsingWhoAndWhom/bhkpph/post.htm) says 
 It's all right to use whom but the explanation in this book says we need to use who here(=the sentence in question).[image]

As per the book the first sentence in picture is correct while the *whom* in second sentence is to be replaced by who because each of  the verbs (marked by V1, V2 and V3) need to have its subject(marked by S1, S2) just like they have in the first sentence given in picture (V1 for S1, V2 for S2) but there is no subject for V3 in second sentence and since whom is objective form not subjective form replace it by *who* to have the missing S3 for V3.
This book isn't written by a native speaker but the writer has written it after consulting about 50 books of native speakers such as Leech & Svartvik, Norman Lewis, J.C. Nesfield etc. But I am not asserting that the writer is  correct The explanation which I shared above may not be a proper grammatical explanation but the writer has shared the above explanation as a *trick* to find error in such questions before this trick he has properly explained the basic who vs whom difference which is available all over the internet. Again I am not asserting that the writer is correct with his *trick*. He may or may not be, I just shared all the information that I had regarding this question.

Comment: Both are correct, but both are not needed. You can say "The guests we were talking about." Btw, can you tell us the name of this book?

Comment: The sentence structure, whether used with a whom or a who is incorrect, lanky at best.

Answer (score 0):

It's a faulty, incomprehensible sentence.   Those verbs do needs subjects, and there simply aren't enough subjects to go around.

The relative clause "whom we were talking about" makes sense.   The subject of this relative clause is "we".   I prefer to avoid stranding the preposition: "about whom we were talking".   Regardless of word order, this "whom" is an object.   In the original word order, it isn't even a *required* object.   Since "whom" is not the subject of the relative clause, we can omit it and allow "we were talking about" to stand as a contact clause.

This clause modifies "guests", allowing "the guests [whom] we were talking about" to serve as the subject of some other verb.   The next available verb in search of a subject is "have".   These guests have come.

So, what do we do with "are my brothers-in-law"?   We can't attach it to "whom", since that already serves as an object within its own clause.   We can't attach it to "guests", since that already serves as (a part of) the subject of "have come".

This book marks "have come" as the third verb.   It doesn't number the finite verbs in order of appearance.   If it is numbering them according to hierarchal depth, then this suggests it expects "have come" to be a part of the relative clause.

> The guests [whom] we were talking about having come are my brothers-in-law.

Here, the topic of conversation isn't merely the guests themselves.   We were talking about having them come, or perhaps talking about them having come.   The non-finite "having" does not require a subject.   Instead, it can itself form a subject, an object or a complement.

Your book contains an error.   "The guests", "we" and "were" are all marked "S1".   Whether it's the author's error, the printer's error, or something else entirely, we have an example that does not make sense as printed.   That alone is enough reason to ignore this specific example.   It's flawed, and we have no way to know how many flaws are hidden within it.

Comment: I have corrected the printer's error in picture by pencil and I think it is legible.

Comment: Yes, your penciled-in corrections are legible.  But, do you trust the source of that correction?  Do you have reason to believe that those labels represent *all* of the errors in that example?  Can you explain the apparent inconsistency of labeling only the "were" of "were talking" but labeling more than the "have" of "have come"?

Comment: Categorically I am not trusting the book, I have mentioned twice in the answer that I am not asserting that he is correct.